# Particular Integral for $x\sin2x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + 4 y = x\sin2x$$
tried solving by $$ {e}^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x $$
$$ P.I. = \frac{1}{D^2+4}xe^{2ix} $$

Comment: Have you tried the Ansatz $Ax\sin2x+Bx\cos2x$?

Comment: I'm getting -x^2/8 * cos2x + (xsin2x)/16 can you please confirm if it's correct??

Comment: @lip Substitution into the ODE shows that works.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients).  The solution to the homogeneous equation is straightforward; call it $h(x)$.  The method of undetermined coefficients then recommends trying the particular solution, where I have already found a large enough power of $x$ to use to produce a particular part that is linearly independent of the homogeneous solution,
$$  h(x) + (a+bx+cx^2)\cos(2x) + (d+ex+fx^2)\sin(2x)  \text{.}  $$

(Generically, how did I find the power of $x$?  I tried $h(x) + (a+bx)\cos(2x) + (d+ex)\sin(2x)$, the base version of the solution by the method of undetermined coefficients, in the differential equation.  The resulting coefficients, $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, either (1) did not have a consistent solution or (2) produced a particular solution in the span of the homogeneous solution.  Then I tried increasing the degrees of the polynomials by $1$ and found that that the coefficient equations could be solved and resulted in a particular solution not in the span of the homogeneous solution.  So this is a usable particular solution.)

Substituting this back into the differential equation, it will turn out that three or more of $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, and $f$ are zero.

Comment: There is nothing random in the selection of the degree of the particular solution. Here the homogeneous solution is in $e^{\pm i2x}$ same as RHS $\sin(2x)$ so we search $\operatorname{degree}(x)+1$ for the particular solution, and we can ignore $a,d$ because it is already solution of homogeneous equation. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3190204/399263

Comment: @zwim : I make no claim that there is something random in the selection of the power.  There is a systematic method using a Jordan block matrix.  However, for sufficiently interesting homogeneous solutions, the power of $x$ required does not have a formulaic prescription, so iteration of degree until a linearly independent solution is produced is the easiest prescription for students.