# using undetermined coefficient cannot solve the second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am wondering this problem,

$$y''-4y'+20y = 8(x+1)e^{2x}\sin(4x)$$
given that $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0) = 0$

I found the general solution by the auxiliary equation: $y_{g} = e^{2x}(c_{1}\cos(4x)+c_{2}\sin(4x))$

I would like to try undetermined coefficient by letting $y_p = (Ax+B)e^{2x}\sin(4x) + (Cx+D)e^{2x}\cos(4x)$
but I find difficulties here...

Comment: The polynomial factor in the RHS is of the first degree and the complex exponential factor is based on a root of the characteristic equation. Hence you should go one degree higher, i.e. quadratic polynomials.

Comment: That means, let  $y_p =(Ax^{2} + Bx + C)e^{2x}sin(4x) + (Dx^{2}+Ex+F)e^{2x}cos(4x) ?$
@YvesDaoust

Comment: Right, that's it.

Comment: Note that the LHS may be written as $y''-4y'+20y=(D^2-4D+20)y=(D-2)^2y+16y$. This suggests the substitution $z=e^{-2x}y$, whence the ODE becomes $z''+16z=8(x+1)\sin(4x).$ That seems distinctly simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer here [Finding particular solutions of $y^{(4)}+2y′′+y=x\sin x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3190204/399263)

$(2\pm 4i)$ is root of the characteristic equation of the ODE, so solutions of the homogeneous part are $$e^{2x}\Big(A\cos(4x)+B\sin(4x)\Big)$$

Your full ODE has a RHS $=P(x)e^{2x}\sin(4x)$ which collides with the same complex roots.

This means a particular solution can be found of the form $e^{2x}\Big(Q_1(x)\sin(4x)+Q_2(x)\cos(4x)\Big)$ with $Q_1,Q_2$ being polynomials of degree $\deg(P)+1=2$

You can omit the part $e^{2x}(A\cos(4x)+B\sin(4x))$ since it's contribution is zero, due to homogeneous solution.

So you search a particular solution in the form $e^{2x}((ax^2+bx)\cos(4x)+(cx^2+dx)\sin(4x))$.

Just substitute in the ODE and identify coefficients with the right hand side.

Comment: I found that a = -1/2, b = 1, c = 0 and d = 1/8, is it correct?

Comment: $b=-1$, the other coefficients are correct, probably just a typo.

Comment: Thanks so much! You just spend around 5 mins to obtain the answer... awesome...!!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Solve for $y''-4y'+20y = 8(x+1)\mathrm e^{(2+4i)x}$, and take the imaginary part of the solution.

Note that $2+4i$ is a simple root of the characteristic equation, sou you should try to determine a solution of the form $p(x)\mathrm e^{(2+4i)x}$, where $p(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: $\sin(4x)$ is a combination of $e^{(2+4i)x}$ and $e^{(2-4i)x}$ so you need two polynomials $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)$.

Comment: @zwim: It is also the imaginary part of $\mathrm e^{1+4i)x$, so you take the imaginary part of the corresponding solution.

Comment: OK, but in this case even for $x$ real $p(x)$ should have complex coefficients (which more or less is equivalent to have two $p_1(x),p_2(x)$ real quadratics), it may not be immediately obvious to the reader, and it does not work otherwise.

Comment: There's only to separate the real imaginary parts of the coefficients, and the real and imaginary parts of $\mathrm e^ {4ix}$ to obtain ultimately the imaginary part of the product. I don't see why this should be a problem – it was not when I was taught to do so.